# Swing screen overlay interfering with mouse when drawing over it

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JFrame` that's transparent always on top and unfocusable so I can use it as a screen overlay. It works, but the problem is: When I put my cursor over somewhere I've drawn something my cursor is always 'above' it so I can not click in the window that's actually in focus. Is there any way to fix this?

```
public class ExternalOverlay extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public Timer timer;
    private float[] res;
    private final int FRAMERATE = 60;

    public ExternalOverlay() {
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        float[] res = this.getRes();
        this.setBounds(0, 0, (int)res[0], (int)res[1]);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        this.setFocusableWindowState(false);
        this.timer = new Timer(1000/FRAMERATE, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    private float[] getRes() {
        if (this.res != null) return res;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double width = screenSize.getWidth();
        double height = screenSize.getHeight();
        return new float[] {(float) width, (float) height};
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.repaint();
    }


    public void draw(Graphics g) {

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // draw
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a JFrame that's transparent

You should be using:

```
frame.setOpacity(0.0f);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html). Download the `TranslucentWindowDemo` code for a good place to start.

Comment: I should have said it has a transparent background

Comment: @Babbaj, What is a transparent background? You say the frame is always overtop so you can use it as an overlay. That tells me the frame is on top of other windows so you can see other windows on the desktop. If you are trying to do custom painting then you should be overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel and then add the panel to the frame. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates your problem, since your question is not clear.